# i am using fopen to read a shared location but unable to read?

Tags: php

I am using fopen to read from a shared location if a files exists on that location. I am doing this in php. But i am not able to do this. However when i access this location directly it is accessible can anybody help with it.

Comment: post what code you tried will help us to resolve?

Comment: Your code is wrong or the file is locked or not readable by the current user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under witch user your apache server runs? Probably this user does not have permission to open this network resource.

Comment: Thanks :-) @shakti see some people can even help without code.